# Using SFTP File Name in Logic Apps

Tags: sftp, azure-logic-apps

I have a simple Logic App that uses a SFTP connector, followed by a condition with an expression that states:

```
Object Name: File Name
Relationship: starts with
Value: '943'
```

The expression ends up being:

```
"@startsWith(triggerOutputs()['headers']['x-ms-file-name'], '''943''')"
```

But the condition always fails even when the file starts with 943.

When trying to debug this I decided to write the "file name" property to the body of a Service Bus Queue and then read it from a simple Windows app. When getting the body as a string, it always threw an exception. I had to rewrite it to use a stream to read it.

Failed Code:

```
Dim s as String = message.GetBody(of String)()
```

Working Code:

```
 Dim stream As Stream = message.GetBody(Of Stream)()
 Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
 Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd
```

Does this mean "file name" is not a string but something else like a byte array?  How do I get my condition in my Logic App to work properly?

Comment: Hi Thomas - we have expression debugging coming soon and hopefully that will make debugging condition statements easier. In the meantime, how I usually debug this is to add a "Compose" action and use "SFTP - File name" token as the input. This way, when you run the Logic App, you can see exactly what the value is.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on how to "debug", it works better than using the Service Bus and writing an app to view it.  As I already confirmed the file name did start with 943, so I don't understand why the condition is returning false instead of true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update

```
"@startsWith(triggerOutputs()['headers']['x-ms-file-name'], '''943''')"
```

to

```
"@startsWith(triggerOutputs()['headers']['x-ms-file-name'], '943')"
```

Looks like basic mode will treat **123** as int, but adding additional quotes when entered **'123'**, so you will need to make the change by switching to advanced mode.